# How to avoid a segment connection between start point and end point on a map view to get printed image with MKMapSnapshotter?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, uibezierpath, mkmapsnapshotter

I'm trying to draw a route on my Map View in Swift.
The below is what I drew with `MKMapSnapshotter`.
My problem is that the first and the last points of my route(coordinate) are always connected by segment so that they looks like a closed loop.
Here, I don't want to draw the segment.

[image]

The following is my code, and please give me some solution for the problem.

```html
func saveMapViewAsImage(region: MKCoordinateRegion, size: CGSize) {
    let options = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
    options.region = region
    options.size = size
    options.mapType = .standard

    MKMapSnapshotter(options: options).start { snapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
        
        let mapImage = snapshot.image
        
        let finalImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
            mapImage.draw(at: .zero)
                
            // get [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
            let coordinates = self.getTrackPointForPolyline()
            guard coordinates.count > 1 else { return }
            
            // [CLLocationCoordinate2D] -> [CGPoint]
            let points = coordinates.map { coordinate in
                snapshot.point(for: coordinate)
            }

            // draw lines
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.lineWidth = K.Map.routeLineWidth * 0.5
            path.lineCapStyle = .round
            path.lineJoinStyle = .round

            path.move(to: points[0])
            for index in 1..<points.count {
                path.addLine(to: points[index])
            }

            K.Map.routeLineColor.withAlphaComponent(0.75).setStroke()
            path.stroke()
        }

        // save as image
        self.saveRenderedImageToDocumentDirectory(image: finalImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: try `path.close()` at the end

Comment: @GerdCastan. I've tried but, both using and not using `path.close()` showed the same result. And I didn't use `path.close()` because I want to prevent segment connection between start point and end point.

Comment: I was fortunate enough to be able to identify the issue in my code on my own. The problem was the number of iterations in the for loop, as points.count had the incorrect value. All the UIBezierPath related code was written correctly and worked well.